# Azure container instance communication between public and private subnet

Tags: azure, azure-container-instances

I deployed in azure a container Instance with a public IP.
I have another azure container Instance connected to a private sub net.

If I try to curl from the public container Instance to the private IP of the other container Instance I get

```
connect to 10.xx.xx.xxx port 3001 failed: Connection timed out
```

How can I let the public container instance open a connection to the private one?

Comment: To allow the public container instance to open a connection to the private one, you need to ensure that the private container instance is accessible from the public IP address. One way to achieve this is by configuring a network security group (NSG) to allow traffic from the public IP address to the private IP address and port. You can create an inbound security rule in the NSG to allow traffic from the public IP address to the private IP address and port.

Comment: You can follow the steps outlined in the "Explore the AKS hybrid environment" document to create a static NAT mapping for the private IP address of the container instance and the port it is listening on. Once the NAT static mapping is created, you can test the access of your application. References:

-   [Explore the AKS hybrid environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/hybrid/aks-hci-evaluation-guide-3#expose-a-nested-application-to-the-internet)

Comment: Create a [virtual network](https://i.imgur.com/gT5ZiB8.png) with two subnets: one for public access and one for private access.Create VNet and a public subnet. Add a private subnet to the existing VNet. Deploy a [container instance](https://i.imgur.com/E5Vo81O.png) into the public subnet. You will need to specify a public IP address for this. Deploy another [container instance](https://i.imgur.com/b0s8Igx.png) into the private subnet. This instance will not have a public IP address and will only be accessible within the virtual network.

Comment: Create [NSG](https://i.imgur.com/dT3p6wA.png) [rules](https://i.imgur.com/0u1t5Wd.png) to allow traffic from the public container to the private container. [Associate](https://i.imgur.com/7K1s8F0.png) NSG to the private subnet. You can test the connectivity from the public container to the private container by [logging](https://i.imgur.com/pww54a7.png) into the public container instance and using a tool like `curl` or [wget](https://i.imgur.com/GOzmotd.png) to access the private container instance.

Comment: Fabry did it resolve your issue?

Comment: Do you want to allow the traffic from "public container instance" to "private container instance" to go via VNET or via Internet?